# How can I pass a string to a C function from Objective-C and get a value back?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I have an Objective-C view controller class, from which I am trying to call a straight-C (not Objective-C) function.  I want to pass in a string variable by reference, set its value inside the C function, and then back in my view controller I want to convert this to a normal NSString object.

Since I can't pass in an NSString object directly, I need to create and pass in either a `char` pointer or a `char` array, and then convert it to an NSString object after the function returns.

Can anyone point me to a simple code example that shows how to do this?  I'm not strong in either Objective-C or regular C, so manipulating strings is extremely difficult for me.

Comment: You can pass Obj-C objects and manipulate them using pure C if you really want to. What does the function you are trying to use do? Is it something you wrote yourself or are you using someone else's code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this

```
bool doSomethingToMyString(const char* originalString, char *buffer, unsigned int size)
{
    bool result = 0;
    if (size >= size_needed)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "The new content for the string, maybe dependent on the originalString.");
        result = 1;
    }
    return result;
}

...
- (void) objectiveCFunctionOrSomething:(NSString *)originalString
{
    char myString[SIZE];
    if (doSomethingToMyString([originalString UTF8String], myString, SIZE))
    {
        NSString *myNSString = [NSString stringWithCString:myString encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        // alright!
    }
}
```

or, you know, something to that effect.

Comment: I think `stringWithCString` is deprecated (not that there's anything wrong with that). :)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `stringWithCString:` is deprecated but `stringWithCString:encoding:` isn't. I may be mistaken though.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following in the `NSString` docs:

```
– cStringUsingEncoding:
– getCString:maxLength:encoding:
– UTF8String
+ stringWithCString:encoding:
```

Comment: My main problem is passing a char array into a C function and getting a value back out, so it's more of a C problem than an Objective-C problem.

Comment: Try char *foo = [myString UTF8String]; char *bar = cfunction(foo); NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithCString:bar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got it to work.  Here is my C function:

```
int testPassingChar(char buffer[]) {    
    strcpy(buffer, "ABCDEFGHIJ");
    return 0;
}
```

And then from Objective-C:

```
char test[10];
int i;
i = testPassingChar(test);
NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:test length:sizeof(test) 
    encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: You should generally avoid having functions do stuff with passed-in buffers without knowing what size they are. (And by "generally" I really mean "always".)

Comment: what walkytalky said. And in your example if you strcpy "ABCDEFGHIJ" into a buffer that is 10 in size, you'll get a buffer overflow from the `"\0"` terminating character.

Comment: @walkytalky: I would indeed prefer to pass in a pointer instead of a pre-allocated buffer, but the above code is the only thing I'm able to get working right now. Also, if I allocate the size of my buffer in the C function, I then have to clean up the memory in Objective-C, which seems odd to me.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: You most certainly do have a buffer overflow. Whether or not it clobbers something important depends on how the compiler decides to arrange the array on the stack (often, the optimization level will affect this)

Comment: @MusiGenesis: The problem of not knowing the length is the same whether you pass in a pointer or a stack-allocated array (although the consequences of overrunning might differ). It's perfectly acceptable to do C-style dynamic allocations with `malloc`/`free` in Objective-C -- there are objecty alternatives if you really want them, but probably superfluous in a case like this. Have your function tell you how much space it needs so you can avoid using a fixed length.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you wrap your C function in Objective-C?

```
-(NSString*)testPassingCharWithStringLength:(int)whateverLength {
     char *test = malloc(sizeof(char) * whateverLength);  
     //do whatever you need to *test here in C
     NSString *returnString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:test];
     free(test);
     return returnString;
}
```

...for example...